# How to check for supported S Pen devices?

Tags: android

How can I determine if a device has S Pen?

Note that I am using `SDrawLibrary.isSupportedModel()` on Samsung S3 it returns true where we all know S3 does not have S Pen.

Any gaudiness or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using has been removed from S Pen SDK. Update SDK to 2.2.5 version, because there was a lot of improvements.

At the moment the library doesn't provide any method to check whether the device has S Pen or not. Use the `Build` class to obtain information about the device, prepare a list containing models which has S Pen, then check if the device is on the list. This is probably not the answer you expected, because it requires to keep the list up to date.

```
private static final String SAMSUNG = "SAMSUNG";
private static final String NOTE = "GT-N";
private static final String SPEN_FEATURE = "com.sec.feature.spen_usp";
private final List<String> mSPenDevices;

public boolean isSPenSupported() {
    FeatureInfo[] infos = getPackageManager().getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    for (FeatureInfo info : infos) {
        if (SPEN_FEATURE.equalsIgnoreCase(info.name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (Build.MODEL.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith(NOTE)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (SAMSUNG.equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        for (String model : mSPenDevices) {
            if (model.equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MODEL)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** Because most of models from Galaxy Note series starts with "GT-N" I added the check to the code. I am aware of devices in the USA has other naming, so this in still not the best solution.

Another possible approach is to check if the device has `com.sec.feature.spen_usp` feature, but as far I know it works starting from JB. I updated the code above.

Comment: I was hoping to find better answer, I had this solution in mind but as you said **it requires to keep the list up to date** I'll mark your solution as an answer till someone else get me a more reliable one.

Comment: does this mean tht only note and samsung devices are supported? No other device running an spen app will work ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also detect S-Pen via InputManager:

```
    boolean sPen = false;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        InputManager inptmgr = (InputManager)getSystemService(INPUT_SERVICE);
        int[] inputs = inptmgr.getInputDeviceIds();
        for(int i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
            if(inptmgr.getInputDevice(inputs[i]).getName().toLowerCase().contains("pen")) sPen = true;
        }
    }
```